# Truncated data in Access 2010 Memo Fields

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010, truncated, memo

Let me start out by saying that I am not an Access person, I struggle with coding so please be patient if I don't grasp everything immediately

I have created a database for my healthcare organization. The purpose of the database is for the liaisons to record their visits with other physicians; I created forms to make it easier for the liaisons. One of the fields I have in the form is a Notes section, I changed the Data Type of this field to Memo to allow them to type in more than the 255 character limit.

The liaisons have entered data into the Memo field and the data is truncated in the table itself. Is there anyway for me to fix this so all of the entered data shows up in the table and in any reports I run?

Thank you

Comment: anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you defined the field as "memo" on the table itslef (and not the form)